# MS Word - create a table with 2 rows, where each row is 50% of the document's height

Tags: microsoft-word

I need to create a table with 2 rows, where each row is 50% of the document's height (assume portrait orientation).  Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided the easiest way to do this was simply to set the row height to 4.5".